# Sentential logic derivation: ~(A ≡ B) ├ (~A ≡ B)

Tags: logic, proof

I am doing some practice sentential derivation proofs for an upcoming test and have attempt the following proof many, many times without success.

~(A ≡ B) ├ (~A ≡ B)

The logic system I am using is the Sentential Logic system which has the following inference rules: Reiteration, Conjunction Introduction/Elimination, Conditional Introduction/Elimination, Negation Introduction/Elimination, Disjunction Introduction/Elimination, and Biconditional Introduction/Elimination.

Answer (score 3):

The bi-conditional is boring because you have to split into two parts:

> 1) **¬[(A→B) ∧ (B→A)]** --- premise

2) **A** --- assumed [a]

3) **B→A** --- from 2)

4) **B** --- assumed [b]

5) **A→B** --- from 4)

6) **(A→B) ∧ (B→A)** --- from 3) and 5)

7) *contradiction !* with 1)

8) **¬A** --- from 2) and 7), discharging [a]

> 9) **B → ¬A** --- from 4) and 8), discharging [b].

In the same way, we have to derive: **¬A  → B**.

10) **¬A** --- assumed [c]

11) **¬B** --- assumed [d]

12) **A** --- assumed [e]

13) *contradiction!* with 10)

14) **B** --- from 13)

15) **A→B** --- from 12) and 14), discharging [e]

16) **B** --- assumed [f]

17) *contradiction!* with 11)

18) **A** --- from 17)

19) **B→A** --- from 16) and 18) discharging [f]

20) **(A→B) ∧ (B→A)** --- from 15) and 19)

21) *contradiction!* with 1)

22) **B** --- from 11) by *Double Negation*, discharging [d]

> 23) **¬A→B** --- from 10) and 22), discharging [c].

Now we conclude from 9) and 23) with:

> > 24) **¬A ≡ B**.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a proof using the Fitch software:

[image]